# Thymeleaf Radio button th:field checked validation

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to validate the input of a radio button created using th:each.
Using th:field in the input outputs checked="checked" in the html which makes one radio button selected onload which I don't want. If I put name="field" then this doesn't happen however validation on the field does not occur as I wouldn't be using th:field.

```
<form th:action="@{/dosomething}" th:object="${Object}" method="post">                                  
<div th:each="op : *{options}"> 
<input type="radio" th:field="*{options}" th:value="${op.id}"     th:id="${opStat.index}"/>                         
<label th:for="${opStat.index}" th:text="${op.optiontext}">Option   Text</label>
<button type="submit">Next</button>                 
</form>

<form action="/dosomething" method="post">                                  
<div>   
<input type="radio" value="1" id="0" name="options" checked="checked"/>                         
<label for="0">A</label>
</div>                                  
<div>   
<input type="radio" value="3" id="1" name="options" checked="checked"/>                         
<label for="1">B</label>
</div>                                  
<div>   
<input type="radio" value="4" id="2" name="options" checked="checked"/>                         
<label for="2">C</label>
</div>                                  
<div>   
<input type="radio" value="2" id="3" name="options" checked="checked"/>                         
<label for="3">D</label>
</div>              
<button type="submit">Next</button>             
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using radio buttons doesn't make sense.  A chosen radio button is a single value, but you are attempting to bind it to an array: `th:field="*{options}"` (rather than a single field, something like `th:field="*{selectedOpId}"` for example).

Your `th:object` should have a field on it to store the results of the radio button choice and your `th:each` should be iterating over a regular model attribute.  Something like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/dosomething}" th:object="${Object}" method="post">
    <th:block th:each="op : ${options}">
        <input type="radio" th:field="*{chosenOptionId}" th:value="${op.id}" th:id="${opStat.index}"/>                         
        <label th:for="${opStat.index}" th:text="${op.optiontext}">Option Text</label>
    <th:block>

    <button type="submit">Next</button>                 
</form>
```